# sending POST request to azure ML Web service using poster

Tags: r, web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

I have successfully deployed a web service using Azure ML and am able to get output both on Azure ML as well as a sample R client application.

I would like to however get response using the firefox poster.

I have followed the instructions from the Azure page on deploying the web service and tried using the same request headers and parameters as follows

Instructions from azure page
[image]

this is what I've tried on Poster
[image]
[image]

Error message
[image]

My R Code which works

```
library("RCurl")
library("rjson")

# Accept SSL certificates issued by public Certificate Authorities
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

h = basicTextGatherer()
hdr = basicHeaderGatherer()


req = list(

        Inputs = list(


            "input1" = list(
                "ColumnNames" = list("Smoker", "GenderCD", "Age"),
                "Values" = list( list( "1", "M", "8" ),  list( "1", "M", "8" )  )
            )                ),
        GlobalParameters = setNames(fromJSON('{}'), character(0))
)

body = enc2utf8(toJSON(req))
api_key = "hHlKbffejMGohso5yiJFke0D9yCKwvcXHG8tfIL2d8ccWZz8DN8nqxh9M4h727uVWPz+jmBgm0tKBLxnPO4RyA=="
authz_hdr = paste('Bearer', api_key, sep=' ')

h$reset()
curlPerform(url = "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/79f267a884464b6a95f5819870787918/services/e3490c06c73849f8a78ff320f7e5ffbc/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true",
            httpheader=c('Content-Type' = "application/json", 'Authorization' = authz_hdr),
            postfields=body,
            writefunction = h$update,
            headerfunction = hdr$update,
            verbose = TRUE
            )

headers = hdr$value()
httpStatus = headers["status"]
if (httpStatus >= 400)
{
    print(paste("The request failed with status code:", httpStatus, sep=" "))

    # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
    print(headers)
}

print("Result:")
result = h$value()
print(fromJSON(result))
```

My API key

```
hHlKbffejMGohso5yiJFke0D9yCKwvcXHG8tfIL2d8ccWZz8DN8nqxh9M4h727uVWPz+jmBgm0tKBLxnPO4RyA==
```

How can I form a correct URL which works?

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "Content to Send" section is incorrect, you have specified URL-encoded, while you need to put application/json.

[image]

Comment: will get back shortly